# Excel - Find All Occurrences of a Specific Value within a Range and Return the Corresponding Value From Row 1

Tags: excel, indexing, match, row

My research has failed me (or perhaps I'm not wording my question properly) on Google and these forums. What I'm trying to do is find all occurrences of -1 from the table in the pic and list out the corresponding values from column A and row 1.

[image: Table]

I am currently able to list the values from column A using:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$2:$G$8=-1,ROW($B$2:$G$8)-1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

It returns:

[image: Name]

But, I've not found any formula that accurately retrieves the value from row 1.

The goal is to have this:

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that to the condition and use COLUMN() for the return and COUNTIF for k.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$G$1,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$G$8=-1)*($A$2:$A$8=J2),COLUMN($B$2:$G$8)-1),COUNTIF($J$2:J2,J2))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This approach spills the expected result including both columns all at once:

```
=LET(sports, B1:G1, names, A2:A8, data, B2:G8, DROP(REDUCE("", names,
 LAMBDA(ac,n, LET(f, FILTER(data, names=n), ff, TOCOL(FILTER(sports, f=-1,"")), 
 IF(@ff="", ac, VSTACK(ac, HSTACK(IF(ff=ff, n), ff)))))),1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

Answer (score 1):

Another way in Excel 365 using Tocol to ignore error values:

```
=LET(Name,A2:A8,
Sport,B1:G1,
data,B2:G8,
Names,IF(data=-1,Name,NA()),
Sports,IF(data=-1,Sport,NA()),
HSTACK(TOCOL(Names,2),TOCOL(Sports,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution Tom!